# Skip bytes in ZipEntry for ZipOutputStream

Tags: java, stream, zip

I am continuing a zipping process that was previously started by another method. I need to start some `bytes` after the `ZipEntry`. I skipped some `bytes` in the `InputStream`, but I need to skip the `ZipEntry` to match.

```
inputStream.skip(bytesToSkip)
```

How do I match the ZipEntry to match? I've been using

```
zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(object.getKey()))
```

This puts the stream at the beginning so when I start streaming again, it streams the `InputStream` at the skipped point and puts it at the beginning of the `ZipOutputStream`. I need to adjust it to skip some `bytes`.

Is there something like this?

```
zipEntry.skip(bytesToSkip)
```

Maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree. Any help is appreciated.

---

EDIT: Updated to address Ramsay

In my scenario, I'm using an `AWS Lambda Function` to zip a folder of files with varying sizes. When there is only a little time left in the `AWS Lambda Function`, I have to clean up everything and call another `AWS Lambda Function` to finish what I started. The second `AWS Lambda Function` has to pick up where the last one stopped so I skip bytes in the `InputStream` to continue where it stopped.

So in a scenario where the first `AWS Lambda Function` was in the middle of zipping file1, I think I'm getting bad zip files because the second `AWS Lambda Function` skips bytes from the `InputStream` of file1, but when I set the `zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(object.getKey()))`, it "puts the stream at the beginning". This doesn't match up with the middle of file1 where I want to pick up from.

Also, there is a chance that I could be wrong and this isn't causing the bad zip files it's producing.

Here's some code snippets:

```
private void upload(ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream) {
    try {
        ListObjectsV2Result result;
        int lenProgress = 0;
        do {
            result = s3Client.listObjectsV2(listObjectsRequest);
            for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : result.getObjectSummaries()) {
                try {
                    S3Object object = s3Client.getObject(objectSummary.getBucketName(), objectSummary.getKey());
                    try (InputStream inputStream = object.getObjectContent()) {
                        inputStream.skip(bytesToSkip );
                        bytesToSkip = 0;
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[BYTE_SIZE];
                        int len;
                        zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(object.getKey()));
                        while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                            zipOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
                            lenProgress += len;
                            if (context.getRemainingTimeInMillis() < ALARM) {
                                cleanUp(lenProgress);
                                return;
                            } 
                        }
                    }
                    lenProgress = 0;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            String nextContinuationToken = result.getNextContinuationToken();
            listObjectsRequest.setContinuationToken(nextContinuationToken);
        } while (result.isTruncated() == true);
    } catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
        System.out.println("Caught an AmazonServiceException, " + "which means your request made it "
                + "to Amazon S3, but was rejected with an error response " + "for some reason.");
        System.out.println("Error Message:    " + ase.getMessage());
        System.out.println("HTTP Status Code: " + ase.getStatusCode());
        System.out.println("AWS Error Code:   " + ase.getErrorCode());
        System.out.println("Error Type:       " + ase.getErrorType());
        System.out.println("Request ID:       " + ase.getRequestId());
    } catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
        System.out.println("Caught an AmazonClientException, " + "which means the client encountered "
                + "an internal error while trying to communicate" + " with S3, "
                + "such as not being able to access the network.");
        System.out.println("Error Message: " + ace.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: if you're going to down vote, could you at least explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to ask yourself what you mean by 'skip bytes in output'. In the input, it has meaning because you effectively ignore bytes as you read, but what does it mean in the output?

When you write to a stream you are writing a continuous stream of bytes. If you *skip*, do you mean that you want a patch of 'no bytes' in the destination zip entry? What does that mean? Perhaps if you explain under what circumstances you might skip bytes in the input we'll understand why you might want to skip bytes in the output.

Or perhaps you actually want a new Zip entry to start where you start using the bytes from the input stream?

Comment: I updated my question with more details. how would go about approaching this? or is the zip entry not the issue?

Comment: "Or perhaps you actually want a new Zip entry to start where you start using the bytes from the input stream?" Yes, I want this.

Comment: Sorry for being spammy, but how do I do that? I've been googling for hours and I can't find it anywhere...

Comment: it looks like i was barking up the wrong tree. thanks for your help.